# Using the DI-Container inside a service

Tags: xml, symfony, service, dependency-injection, containers

I'm still fairly new to Symfony. I already know that you can create a service and register it in a services.xml file.

As far as I know, there are two ways of how to use other services inside a service:

1) In the services.xml file, you add an  tag for every service you want to use. In the __construct method of your corresponding service-class, you assign services to different variables and then can access the services through these variables.

2) In the services.xml file, you add an  tag for the service_container. In the __construct method the of your corresponding service-class, you now assign the service_container to a variable and then can access other services through the container-variable.

My question is, which of these two ways is 'better practce'?

Comment: The first way is definitely the better approach as long as you know which services you need in advance.  The second approach is known as a service locator.  You can search for the term to research the downsides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short anwser: the first solution is prefred

The first (preferred) solution is known as dependency injection and it's mostly favored over the second (service locator) approach.
Dependency injection has a couple of advantages over the service locator approach:

- Reusable code: you're injecting the value, thereby configuring the service externally
- Testable code: instead of injecting the real object you can inject mock object
- Readability: your dependencies are visible in the interface

The main reason I'd use the service locator is to do lazy instantiation to gain some performance.

*Note that there may be more advantages/disadvantages to both techniques.*